# How to delete row from table in angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms

This is my function to delete row from table this function is working fine as it is deleting the row. but after refreshing deleted row is displaying again. So how do i solve this problem.

```
deleteListItem(id:number, index:number){
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete"))
      this.paymentDataService.deleteItem(id).subscribe(response =>{
      this.paymentLists.splice(index, 1);
    });
 }
```

This is html when data is displaying.

```
 <tr *ngFor ="let payment of paymentLists; let i = index">
      <td>{{ payment.datesent}}</td>
      <td>{{ payment.amount | currency:'USD':true}}</td>
      <td>{{ payment.paymenttype}}</td>
      <td>{{ payment.paymentdates}}</td>
      <td><button (click)="deleteListItem(payment.id, i)" type="button">Delete</button>
           </td>
```

Comment: is element is deleted in list>>can you check the list

Comment: Yes element is deleted i checked it. But after refreshing its again displaying.

Comment: then i think angular cannot detect changes check this out..[change detection in angular](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Comment: I used it then also getting the same problem.

Comment: then I think the issue is related to backend..must check if the item is deleted in backend or not otherwise I don't seem any issue related angular

Comment: You need to store your data because after refreshing angular app is also refresh from beginning hence you need to use local or session storages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your data because after refreshing angular app is also refresh from beginning hence you need to use local or session storage.

```
deleteListItem(id:number, index:number){
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete"))
      this.paymentDataService.deleteItem(id).subscribe(response =>{
      this.paymentLists.splice(index, 1);                                                          
      localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify( this.paymentLists ));
    });
 }     

And in you need to retreive in onInit function lifecycle hook of your component

ngOnInit(): void {
this.paymentLists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key')) || [];
}
```

Comment: Its also displaying the same output.

Comment: Ideally localStorage should definitely work only thing you need to set and get in proper place, please check if you are not re-initializing this paymentLists event after getting from local storage this.paymentLists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key')) || [];.. IT would be great if you can share complete code of your component